# Measuring tape and conversion - luggage size

Tags: hand-luggage

I m travelling and the luggage bag need to be 55x40x20cm . Now I’m not a math expert but how can we get a idea how big the bag is?

Below is a measurement tape but I do not know how to measure as per google if I do 55cm to m, it is 0.5m which is less than one like a pea size, which cannot be right.
How can I measure my bag with pictured measuring tap? And a general rule of thumb is ?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. 55 centimeters is exactly equal to 0.55 meters. That's much, much larger than a pea, of course. Are you asking whether your measuring tape is defective? Are you asking how big 55 centimeters is? Are you asking how to measure things with a measuring tape?

Comment: You measure your bag with the measuring tape in exactly the same way as you use the tape to measure the dimensions of any other object.

Comment: In case you're used to feet and inches, 55 cm is a bit more than 21.5 inches or 1 ft 8.5 inches.  The conversion is 2.54 cm per inch exactly.

Comment: You don't have to use google, one of the advantages of using a measurement system having prefixes (based on the numeric system we commonly use) is that 'c' in front always means 1/100, so 55 cm is 0,55 m (and 55 cL is 0,55 L).

Comment: If I do 21.65 inches to yards, it is 0.6 yards which is less than one like a pea size ...

Comment: You have 16cm visible in your first picture.  Another 4cm will give you the 20cm you need for the shortest side of your bag

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity with the correction that a litre is l not L of course :-)

Comment: @localhost Sorry, but I have never heard of an average pea being larger than 1.8 feet (or just under 55 cm ; 1 meter is subdivided into either **centi**meter [cm] ([Centi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centi-) being one hundredth) or **milli**meter [mm] ([Milli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milli-) being one thousandth). This is what you see on the measuring band: 1cm (subdivided into 10 millimeter portions). Assuming that the average pea size is 10mm (or 1.cm or 0.01m(eter) or 0.3937007874 inch), I would say that 0.5m (or 50 cm or 500 mm or 19.6850393701 inches) would be the size of 50 peas.

Comment: @jcaron: From wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units): 'Since 1979, the litre may exceptionally be written using either an uppercase "L" or a lowercase "l", a decision prompted by the similarity of the lowercase letter "l" to the numeral "1", especially with certain typefaces or English-style handwriting. The American NIST recommends that within the United States "L" be used rather than "l".' So I'm not only right, I follow the recommendation from NIST (who are actually sane in this regard, even though most americans use silly units)

Comment: And 10mm is more than any pea I've seen. I would be likely to guess the size of an average pea to around 0,55 *centi*meters, so the bag can be around 100 peas long. But I doubt that a discussion about pea sizes will help the OP.

Comment: And if anybody wants to abuse the prefixes, 100 peas *can* be called a "hekto-pea", but while some people might *understand* that, I doubt that anyone would find it sane (I should probably head of to bed now).

Answer (score 3):

One unit (i.e. the numbers, or the lines that take the full width of the tape) on your tape is 1 cm, not 1 m. It says “meter” because that’s the base unit (1 cm is one hundredth of one meter), just to distinguish it from inches or other measurements (in some cases you may actually have two sides on the tape: one in cm/m and the other in inches). It does not mean that each unit is one meter.

The full tape is probably somewhere between 1 and 2 meters long (100 and 200 cm), most likely 1.5 meters (150 cm).

The smaller lines in the edge each mark 1 mm (0.1 cm, 0.001 m). The slightly longer ones each mark 5 mm (0.5 cm, 0.005 m). The full-with lines each mark 1 cm (10 mm, 0.01 m).

For reference, the average height of an adult male is between 160 cm and 180 cm (1.6 m and 1.8 m) depending on the country.

So your bag must have its dimensions below 55 units for the longest one, below 40 units on the next largest one, and below 20 for the final one.

My guess from the pictures is that you probably won’t have any issues for the first two, but that you bag is too “thick” for the last one, but you’ll be able to find out yourself by measuring it.

Comment: Since the bag appears to be flexible it is important to note that it will typically be allowed if it can be squeezed to fit in a box of the given dimensions.

Comment: ... and some airline check-in desks do have a metal cage that your bag must be able to fit it.

Comment: Looking at the pictures I doubt whether that bag can be squeezed into such a cage. But it's just a guess.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity yes and I don’t wanna throw away stuff like they say leave it or pay. Paying is hefty too.

Comment: @localhost The standard trick is to take as much as possible out of your bag and wear it on your person.  The airline only cares that the *bag* meets size specifications, but there are generally no size specifications for *people* (assuming you are not so large that the airline requires you to purchase 2 seats)

Comment: @PeterM please keep this trick for the ones able to think it.

Comment: @EarlGrey I used that trick once when an airline tried to charge me for a bag that was one or two kg over the limit (in fact I had several layers of clothing in the bag that I genuinely intended to put on because it was an intercontinental flight home, and I had been uncomfortably cold on the way out, but when the staff saw that I was intending to put on a long-sleeved t-shirt, a button-down shirt, and a sweater, they told me to proceed without waiting for me to finish putting them on, without reweighing the bag, and without charging me.)